# Parameterized Jenkins Pipeline Properties: Can't use parameters on properties section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to set properties by jobs actual name.

My pipeline header looks as follows:

```
def jobs_actual_name = [
       choice(name: 'var', choices: ['choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3']),
    ]

properties([
    parameters(jobs_actual_name)
])
```

The upper pipeline works fine but I want to use a parameter instead of directly giving the name.
Like:

```
def jobs_actual_name = [
       choice(name: 'var', choices: ['choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3']),
    ]
def another_jobs_actual_name = [
       choice(name: 'var', choices: ['choice1', 'choice2', 'choice3']),
    ]

properties([
    parameters("${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}")
])
```

How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some logic execute before setting the properties:

```
def actualParameters = (env.JOB_BASE_NAME == 'jobs_actual_name' ? jobs_actual_name : another_jobs_actual_name)

properties([
    parameters(actualParameters)
])
```